# Craft 3 updates & plugins without allow_url_fopen or SSH

Tags: craft3, updates, manual-updates, hosting

I have set up a Craft 3 site on shared hosting. When I try to update Craft or install plugins via the CP, I get the following error:

> The "https://composer.craftcms.com/packages.json" file could not be
>   downloaded: allow_url_fopen must be enabled in php.ini

allow_url_fopen cannot be enabled on this hosting & there is no SSH access

What are my options for updating Craft & installing/updating plugins in this scenario?

Is the only option to avoid CMS access temporarily, copy down the live database, do any updating locally and then upload the file changes & update the live database?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the only option to avoid CMS access temporarily, copy down the live database, do any updating locally and then upload the file changes & update the live database?

Pretty much.  You'll want to lock the version of PHP in your composer.json file to whatever your production PHP version is so you don't pull in dependencies locally running a higher version of PHP that you deploy live.  You can do that like so:  https://github.com/pixelandtonic/craftnet/blob/develop/composer.json#L46-L50

Note that `allow_url_fopen` is a Composer requirement... there are several issues in their repo of people running into this: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+allow_url_fopen